# Can I use .load() JQuery function to process a form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple question. I have searched online for the answer but have not found one.

Basically, I have an ASPX page `form.aspx` that contains a form and logic to handle that form in the code behind.

I have written code to load the `form.aspx` page into a `<div>` that is on lets say `process.aspx`. To load `form.aspx` into `process.aspx`, I used the `.load()` function from jQuery and it renders correctly.

My question now is, can I load the form with the `.load()` function and still process the form? I will be trying to incorporate AJAX for the submit as well.

I know that It works in terms of rendering, I'm just not sure if this method is meant to render and allows me to process the rendered form on submit.

Does anyone have any experience with the `.load()` function or am I just using the method incorrectly?

Comment: I would suggest not using a method called `load` to submit form data to a server. If you do, comment the heck out of the code so people who come back to it later (including perhaps yourself) know why it was done.

Comment: I see thank you, I will take that advice and use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can use .load() to do both a Post or a Get. So in theory you could use it to process any values submitted in the specified data parameter.

Comment: Thank you Theo for the answer. I will try to take this route and see what happens. I have tried userControls, updatePanels, AJAX extensions in VS. I guess I will have to do the manual, grind way. Thanks Again.